# How to bind static library in a dynamic one in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, static-linking

I have this static(.a/.lib) library which I wanted to bind in my dynamic(.dll).
Lets say the static library is `libColors.a` and the dynamic is `SWC.dll`.
Now I already change the `libColors.a` project properties to make a static library--build it--and I haven't found any `.dll` created, only the .o and .a files which is expected. I switched to my `SWC.dll` project and change its properties to make a dynamic library and check the box to create also a .a file--link the `libColors.a`--build it--and the .dll file is created. (also note that I put `__declspec(import/export)` specification on its `class`es)

Now I want this `SWC.dll` to use in an executable file. However, when I include only the `SWC.h` file in the executable, it gets tons of undefined references. Seems there's a problem here since I didn't call any functions on `SWC.h`. So, I add on my .exe build options the `SWC.a`, now it builds with no error. But when I run it, it says I needed the `Colors.dll`? What do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools like objdump, [CFF Explorer](http://www.ntcore.com/exsuite.php) or [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to view the import table of the PE-COFF executable in question.

The likely explanation is that the way your `Colors` project is compiled isn't really a static library. You can check this by inspecting both `SWC.dll` and your test executable's import table. Chances are that you'll find an import entry from `Colors.dll` in one of them and what function's it's trying to import.

Check the data and functions declared in `Color.h` and make sure they're not decorated with `__declspec()` anywhere. If the functions in `Color.h` preprocesses into something like `__declspec(dllimport)` in 'SWC' this can cause the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for your time reading my question. But I already figure out what's the problem here. I link to an outdated version of the .lib file. Anyway, what is the name of the tool again? I think that would help my future project if I ever encounter this problem again. Does it checks for all the library which are all be linking in that particular program?

Comment: @mr5 I've added links for the tools. `objdump.exe` is a commandline tool that comes with mingw btw. You can use any of the mentioned tools to see what dll's a given executable or dll depends on.